# datatable: automatical refresh after a specified time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Could you recommend me some easy way to automatically refresh of `dataTable` each e.g. 10 minutes?

```
<rich:dataTable id="table" var="item" value="#{bean.model}">    
  <rich:columnGroup>
    <rich:column><h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/></rich:column>
    <rich:column><h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/></rich:column>
    ...
  </rich:columnGroup>

  <f:facet name="footer">  
    <h:commandButton id="load" action="#{bean.loadData}"/>
  </f:facet>    
</rich:dataTable>
```

I've tried a few ways but it always had a catch, so I'm looking for some common method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Richfaces `a4j:poll` ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_poll.html))

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:poll id="poll" interval="600000" reRender="table"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Super, it really worked (but without ui:composition, i had to use normal html tags), thanks!:-)